# C# web service and static DB Connection

Tags: c#, web-services, oracle, oledbconnection

If I crate a `static DB Connection` into a `C# Web service`

This instance of connection is shared on all istance of web service? So, In this way could I have problem some this?

> Not allowed to change the 'ConnectionString' property while the
>   connection (state=Connecting)

I get the instance in this way:

```
  public static OleDbConnection GetDatabaseConnection(string aConnectionString) 
  {
   if (_dbConnection == null) 
   {
    _dbConnection = new OleDbConnection(aConnectionString);
    _dbConnection.Open();
   }
   else 
   {
    _dbConnection.Close();
    _dbConnection = new OleDbConnection(aConnectionString);
    _dbConnection.Open();
   }
   Log.Logger.log("Aperta connessione al DB");
   return _dbConnection;
  }
```

Comment: Which line throws this exception. BTW: What if two concurrent service calls happen? While one of them doing some db operations, seems like other request will close its connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is always a bad practice to keep a global connection instance. You should follow the standard pattern: `create, open, use, close and destroy`.
Working against this will result, sooner or later, in problems.
The [Connection Pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) mechanism has been studied just for this.
The Pool will help you to avoid this bad habit to keep an object so expensive like a database connection open for unforeseeable time

```
public static OleDbConnection GetDatabaseConnection(string aConnectionString) 
{
    OleDbConnection odb = new OleDbConnection(aConnectionString);
    odb.Open();
    Log.Logger.log("Aperta connessione al DB");
    return odb;
}
```

then your client code use the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) to close and destroy the connection

```
using(OleDbConnection cn = SqlClassHelper.GetDatabaseConnection(constring))
{

    // define here your OleDbCommand, OleDbDataReader etc...
    // use the objects

} // <- here the closing brace close and destroy the connection
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will have problems with your code in a multithreaded web service.

Your function `GetDatabaseConnection` works like a factory, everybody who calls it gets a new instance of connection. You do not need static `_dbConnection` class member, just make it a local variable:

```
  public static OleDbConnection GetDatabaseConnection(string aConnectionString) 
  {
    OleDbConnection _dbConnection  = new OleDbConnection(aConnectionString);
    _dbConnection.Open();
    Log.Logger.log("Aperta connessione al DB");
    return _dbConnection;
  }
```